# Search WordPress Hook for completed Elementor Update

Tags: hooks, updates

I am using WordPress and Elementor and looking for a hook that will fire when an Elementor update is completed.

The hook should execute the Elementor function
[Regenerating CSS](https://elementor.com/help/custom-css-not-working/).

This Elementor code should be executed with it:

```
function clear_elementor_cache() {
  // Make sure that Elementor loaded and the hook fired
  if ( did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
  // Automatically purge and regenerate the Elementor CSS cache
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->files_manager->clear_cache();
  }
}
```

[Code Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388444/)

**How do I use the WordPress hook "[upgrader_process_complete](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/)" to clear the Elementor cache?**

Comment: have you asked this in an Elementor community? 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
add_action('upgrader_process_complete', 'my_clear_elementor_cache');
function my_clear_elementor_cache()
{
    // Make sure that Elementor loaded and the hook fired
    if (did_action('elementor/loaded')) {
        // Automatically purge and regenerate the Elementor CSS cache
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->files_manager->clear_cache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
How to extend the code to run only on Elementor or Elementor Pro update?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to fire a hook after Elementor update:

```
function my_after_elementor_update_action( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
    // Check if it's the update of the Elementor plugin
    $elementor_plugin_slug = 'elementor/elementor.php';

if ( isset( $options['action'] ) && $options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' ) {
        foreach ( $options['plugins'] as $plugin ) {
            if ( $plugin == $elementor_plugin_slug ) {
                // Perform your action here after the Elementor plugin update
                // For example, automatically purge and regenerate the Elementor CSS cache
                if ( did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
                    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->files_manager->clear_cache();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'my_after_elementor_update_action', 10, 2 );
```